# How to git cherry-pick commits from a deleted remote branch?

Tags: git

```
          A--B--C--D = Local + RemoteTracking + Origin: Branch1 {I want ?, E, F from below)
         /
        /     /--?--E--F--G = Branch2 (deleted after merge into Master)
       /     /             \
<--H--/--?--/--I--J---------K--L = Local + RemoteTracking + Origin: Master
```

I live on Branch1 (very old and unmerged with Master) and need a few commits from a remote Branch2 that has since been merged back into Master. I don't know the total commit history of Branch2 but know I *probably* need about 3 commits from it (?, E, F). However, I cannot figure out how to find and cherry-pick these exact commits since I can no longer clone this deleted repository.

I cannot tell the history of Branch1 via GitLab/gitk and cannot bring it up in `gitlab.com/../branches`. I can't use merge-base because I cannot clone the deleted repo. I get a "Fatal: Ambiguous argument" when I try `git reflog show Branch2`.

Comment: The branch was merged _for real_ or it was a squash-or-rebase?

Comment: @eftshift0 I know Branch2 was merged into Master via merge request. It's possibly it was squashed into only one commit (i.e. ?, E, F, G are all in just one commit now) but how would I ensure that's the case? I assume your suggestion that, if it was all squashed (and I can confirm) that I don't need to worry about this and just cherry-pick the one squash. In the negative case, I'd still like to know how to do this if it wasn't squashed.

Comment: If it had been a _real_ merge, then the fact that the original branch was deleted makes no difference cause the original commits would still be there (you just need to find the merge and you would see the original commits on one of the parents of the merge)... but if it was squashed, then you _can't_ get it back _unless_ you have a local copy of the original branch (local branches are not deleted when a remote branch is deleted.... as long as it was visible to you at a point and you fetched, which happens when you pull also).

Comment: I do not have any local copies/clones of the Branch2, I only know by the comments of the merge commit from Branch2>Master that I need some commits from that Branch2.

Comment: Do you know the commits `I` and `K` ?

Comment: @Ôrel I know K, not I.

Comment: If you have G and K you can ask to git the common ancestor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- With GitLab: Use Repository > Graph to trace the branch visually. Or even better, go to the Merge Request from `K` and > Overview for Parents, or > Commits where you'd learn what commits there were from that branch/merge to then cherry-pick.
- From command-line or Git-Bash: I could have looked `G` or `K` up through the `git reflog` (or `git log` from the Master) if I didn't already know it. But then you could simply `git checkout` that commit and then `git log` or `gitk` from that commit and learned its history.

In my particular case, @eftshift0 was correct in that all commits had been squashed and after @Ôrel's comment I realized I could just find `K` and singularly cherry-pick `G`. (If there's a better global/all-case answer I'll take it).